# Image download code works for all image format, issues with PNG format rendering

Tags: android, imageview, imagedownload

I am using the code below to download and show image from server to my ImageView

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HTTPTest extends Activity {


     ImageView imView;
     String imageUrl="http://11.0.6.23/";
     Random r= new Random();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button bt3= (Button)findViewById(R.id.get_imagebt);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(getImgListener);
        imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imview);
    }    

    View.OnClickListener getImgListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               //i tried to randomize the file download, in my server i put 4 files with name like
                        //png0.png, png1.png, png2.png so different file is downloaded in button press
               int i =r.nextInt(4);
               downloadFile(imageUrl+"png"+i+".png");
               Log.i("im url",imageUrl+"png"+i+".png");
          }

    };


    Bitmap bmImg;
    void downloadFile(String fileUrl){
          URL myFileUrl =null;          
          try {
               myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
               HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
               conn.setDoInput(true);
               conn.connect();
               int length = conn.getContentLength();
               InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

               bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
               imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
          } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

This code works file for all format of images but when it comes to PNG it wont let the image transparent after download and displaying on ImageView.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know it will be a solution for you or not

But you can use a `Drawable` instead of `Bitmap`

Here is the code

```
void downloadFile(String fileUrl) {
try{
      InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(fileUrl).getContent();
      Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
      imgView.setImageDrawable(d);            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }

}
```

This will show a `png` correctly